# how to delete character in ruby command line

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a .txt file that contain my schedule of playlist for my tv channel. In the file there are many  characters as '**logo_0 2**' in. I run a ruby command to process the playlist (.txt file). How i want to delete these all '**logo_0 2**' in the ruby ? Attached herewith is the .txt file and the rb file to execute the process. I need to eliminate the '**logo_0 2**' in .txt file.

```
ITEM
preset_date 04/08/16
preset_time 22:09:00:00
title Awani (Comedy) Obviously Harith Iskander Sat Ep11 : Logo Inti College + Air Asia + Radio (E) Aug06 Sat 9.30pm
clip HUZKN01HM01AS
in_src 928500
out_src 929250
mode 1
no_vision_trans 1
no_audio_trans 1
type 1
logo_0 2
user_data 05_I_148671633
aspect_ratio 2
channel_id 2
use_subtitle 0
end
ITEM
preset_date 04/08/16
preset_time 22:09:30:00
title RiaHD (Series) Lelaki Macam Dia : Generic (Bm) Isnin - Khamis @ 2200
clip HUJST01HM01DV
in_src 1018125
out_src 1018875
mode 1
no_vision_trans 1
no_audio_trans 1
type 1
logo_0 2
user_data 05_I_148669553
aspect_ratio 2
channel_id 2
use_subtitle 0
end
ITEM
preset_date 04/08/16
preset_time 22:10:00:00
title Citra Mustika (Movie Compact) August Highlights (Bm)
clip HUXAP01HM01CM
in_src 962500
out_src 963250
mode 1
no_vision_trans 1
no_audio_trans 1
type 1
logo_0 2
user_data 05_I_148671344
aspect_ratio 2
channel_id 2
use_subtitle 0
end
ITEM
preset_date 04/08/16
preset_time 22:10:30:00
title Awani (News) Awani 7.45 (Bm) Setiap Hari @ 1945
clip HULHP01HM01AE
in_src 909000
out_src 909750
mode 1
no_vision_trans 1
no_audio_trans 1
type 1
logo_0 2
user_data 05_I_148671634
aspect_ratio 2
channel_id 2
use_subtitle 0
end
ITEM
preset_date 04/08/16
preset_time 22:11:00:00
title Episode Number 880
clip TAPE_REPLACEMENT
in_src 0
out_src 12000
mode 1
no_vision_trans 1
no_audio_trans 1
type 1
logo_0 1
notes Isu utama harian dan mingguan dikupas dengan mendalam oleh ahli panel.
user_data 05_P_174282654
logo_data_0 0
channel_id 2
end
ITEM
preset_date 04/08/16
preset_time 22:19:00:00
title Awani (News) Buletin Awani Noon (Bm) Setiap Hari @ 1200
clip HUUIL01HM01AI
in_src 915000
out_src 915750
mode 1
no_vision_trans 1
no_audio_trans 1
type 1
logo_0 2
user_data 05_I_148671635
aspect_ratio 2
channel_id 2
use_subtitle 0
end
ITEM
preset_date 04/08/16
preset_time 22:19:30:00
title Sports Rio Olympics 2016 - Opening Ceremony (BM) Live Aug6 6.55am
clip HUUUY01HM01AB
in_src 904000
out_src 904750
mode 1
no_vision_trans 1
no_audio_trans 1
type 1
logo_0 2
user_data 05_I_148668511
aspect_ratio 2
channel_id 2
use_subtitle 0
end
ITEM
preset_date 04/08/16
preset_time 22:20:00:00
title Awani (Biz News) Bisnes Awani Plus (Bm) Sabtu @ 1830
clip HPVAP01HM01DU
in_src 1050000
out_src 1050750
mode 1
no_vision_trans 1
no_audio_trans 1
type 1
logo_0 2
user_data 05_I_148671638
aspect_ratio 2
channel_id 2
use_subtitle 0
end
```

Comment: Please limit the txt file to a [minimal set](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that describes the problem, and also add the promised ruby code snippet. Also, take a look at the "How to Format" box on the side of your screen - you'll want to indent your txt file data example and code with 4 spaces so we can read it...

Comment: And where is the rb file?

Comment: Do you want to delete the entire lines or just remove these chars?

Comment: i want to delete the entire 'logo_0 2' in the whole  txt file. I already add the rb file for your info

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you share your ruby code and we can show you how to update it.

```rb
filename = 'item.txt'
contents=File.read(filename)
contents.gsub!("logo_0 2\n", '')
File.open(filename, "w") { |f| f << contents }
```

In case you only want to replace characters `contents.gsub!("logo_0 2", '')` use this statement in place of `contents.gsub!("logo_0 2\n", '')`

Comment: I already share my rb file. You can have a look on that. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @uzairi Cannot see it yet. Can you check again?

Comment: i cant attach the ruby code. Can you suggest any other way so that  can share it? it seems the code is too long to attach here.

Comment: No need to share the whole file. You can share the code snippet where you are trying out this logic (that should be small).

Comment: bstatus = 1
 master = ''
 recmaster.each do | rs |
  # puts "\n--\n" + rs + "\n--\n"
  rs = rs.gsub(/^logo_0 2/, '')

Comment: @uzairi It might be as you are doing ^ in the starting of regex. See this https://repl.it/DSrr. If you use this program as your playground and use ^ in the starting of gsub the output would differ.